# How to parse date with NSDateFormatter with timezone?

Tags: ios, date, nsdateformatter

This is the date format I'm getting back from the server:

> Tue Apr 05 2016 23:59:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)

This is what I have so far: "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z (zzz)"

Which characters are having trouble parsing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date format should be the following:

```
"EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'ZZZZ (zzz)"
```

Demo:

```
let dateString = "Tue Apr 05 2016 23:59:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'ZZZZ (zzz)"

let date = formatter.dateFromString(dateString)
print(date)
>>> Optional(2016-04-06 06:59:00 +0000)
```

Comment: If you change `GMT-0700` to `GMT-07:00`, you can delete `'GMT'` and just use `ZZZZ` instead.